# select always x rows from table and start over when at the end

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, union

I want to create a `PROCEDURE` in **MySQL** that always returns `x` rows from a table, even when the table has less than `x` entries.

Like so:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |    CALL myProcedure USING(4);
+----+-------+    returns →  a b c a
|  1 |   a   |    
|  2 |   b   |    
|  3 |   c   |
+----+-------+
```

Internally I store the last returned row (in this case it would be `'a'`) and on the next call the procedure should continue from there:

```
1st:  CALL myProcedure USING(4) →  a b c a
2nd:  CALL myProcedure USING(3) →    b c a
3rd:  CALL myProcedure USING(7) →    b c a b c a b
4th:  CALL myProcedure USING(2) →      c a
```

I tried it with `UNION` - this is what the 3rd call with x=7 would look like:

```
(
 SELECT `value` 
   FROM `table` 
  LIMIT 1,7
)
UNION
(
 SELECT `value` 
   FROM `table` 
  LIMIT 4
)
```

*"give me as much as you can (up to 7) rows and start after row 1.

  Then start over and give me the rest (7 - number of previous rows = 4)."*

The first select returns `b c` and the second select returns `a b c`. Both selects together return `b c a`.

Now I am facing **these problems**:

**1)**`UNION` does not return the same row twice (all I would get from above call would be `b c a`)

**2)**  At best I can "loop over my table" twice because there is only one union and I have no way of dynamically adding more unions. So even if I could get duplicate rows, it would only result in `b c a b c` and the remaining `a b` I expect will be missing.

**How can I "loop" over my table multiple times?** Is there anything better than `UNION` I could use?

**EDIT (after solving my problem)**
I followed [cf_en's proposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47203712/896249) to loop through the result set outside the database if the returned number of rows is less than expected. All other cases (those that only need one iteration) are covered by the procedure (using a simple `UNION`).

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL` to stop the union from removing duplicates. However, I wonder if the database is the best place to do the looping around. Could you implement this logic in the calling code instead?

Comment: :) awesome, didn't know about `UNION ALL`. Now it "loops" at least twice. Well I was thinking of making supplement calls if the calling code detects that not all expected results where returned. Though I would like to reduce the number of round trips to the database and have the logic all in one place.

Comment: I meant you can just get the unique data rows from the database, and handle all of the looping logic in the calling code instead.

Comment: Of course! Good idea, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: @cf_en As you said, I implemented all the looping outside of MySQL. The only problem there was to figure out which will be the next "last row" that would have been returned if the looping where done by MySQL. Because that information is managed by the database alone. Well, it works now, thank you. Since you helped me solve the problem, maybe you want to write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm not sure it's really an answer to the question but sure, why not. I was kind of aware that resuming from the right place was part of the problem that you would have to solve in moving the logic out of the database. Anyway, I'm glad you got it sorted and happy I was able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to stop the union from removing duplicates. However, I wonder if the database is the best place to do the looping around. Could you return the distinct rows from the database and implement the looping logic in the calling code instead?